# $g \circ f$ is differentiable if and only if $g$ is differentiable

Tags: analysis

I was trying prove the reciprocal of [these results](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271135/is-a-map-g-composed-with-a-local-diffeomorphism-smooth-iff-g-is-smooth), i.e., the case where $g \circ f$ differentiable imply $g$ is differentiable and I think that I will prove the reciprocal if I can prove for the Euclidean case because the case for smooth manifold will be consequence when I see the local representation of these functions, so I would like to receive a hint or a reference for the reciprocals in the Euclidean case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $f$ be any non-differentiable function and let $g$ be the identity function. What can you conclude?

Comment: According to the chain rule, $f \circ g$ is differentiable if both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable.

Comment: @JohnDouma, $g \circ f$ is non-differentiable. Is there any additional assumption that I can put to ensure the "if and only if"?